# True/false : If $K$ be compact neighbourhood of $x$ and $U \subset K$ be a open neighbourhood of $x$ then $ K \setminus U$ is compact

Tags: general-topology

Given $X $ is locally compact Hausdorff space

Is the following statement is true/false

**If $K$ be compact neighbourhood of  $x$ and $U \subset K$ be a open neighbourhood of $x$ then $ K \setminus U$ is compact** ?

**My attempt** : I think this statement is false

take $X=[0,1]$, $K= [1/3,1/2]$ and  $U= (1/3,1/2)$

$K \setminus U= [1/3,/1/2]-(1/3,1/2)=\{1/3,1/2\}$

$\{1/3,1/2\} $is not compact because $f :[0,1] \to \{1/3,1/2\}$   will not be continious

Comment: Of course $\{1/3,1/2\}$ is compact: it’s **finite**, so trivially every open cover of it has a finite subcover.

Comment: $K\setminus U=K \cap U^{c}$ is a closed subset of  a compact set , so it is compact.

Comment: A compact space need not be connected and certainly need not be path-connected.

Comment: What’s $f$ even?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$K \setminus U= K \cap (X\setminus U)$ is a closed subset of $K$ so compact.
And a finite set is **certainly** compact; nothing to do with continuity, just definitions.